# Install Win 7 Pro in a different language

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installation, language-pack

I just bought a new laptop that came with Windows 7 Pro 64bit in Italian.
I'd like to have it in English, but language packs are an option available only with the Ultimate version.

Can I install the English version downloading the official DVD available from Digital River but using my actual product key? Is it legal/possible?

Comment: During installation, you should be able to pick your language (it's actually the first step). The license key is not tied to a specific language version of Windows 7. The benefit with the Ultimate edition is being able to seamlessly switch languages *after* installation.

Comment: I have the original dvd that came with the laptop, but if I try to reinstall the operating system (restarting the machine with the dvd in it) it let me only select Italian. No other languages are available..

Comment: Okay, weird. I was not aware of a situation like that. Sorry  :( Under this circumstance, I'm not sure if using a copy from Digital River will work. Might be worth trying though.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Perhaps the DVD he got with his laptop is an OEM version that's language specific? I think using the English Win7 Pro ISO is a good idea, and as a bonus there'll be no crapware!

Comment: @Stefano: See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) for the ISO.

Comment: Yes, my dvd is an OEM version. I'll try with an english iso and see if it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm responding just to confirm that **it works**.

I've downloaded and installed the english iso of Windows 7 Professional from Digital River, used my product key and activated it online.